# How do I resize the Logical Disk Manager container size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10, fedora

After reading [Fedora installer does not see free space](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/49597/fedora-installer-does-not-see-free-space/)

I'm trying to install Fedora on my HP laptop which already has Windows 10 installed (with 3 primary partitions: C:, system recovery, and HP Tools).

I would like to avoid wiping the entire disk.

My understanding of the Windows Logical Disk Manager so far, is that my entire HDD is still controlled by Windows.
So even if my Windows Disk Management( via mmc) says 300GB is unallocated, it is still within the control of Windows.

So I need to shrink the amount of disk space that Windows controls. 
The answer from Ask Fedora suggests that I find "some way" to shrink the LDM "container" size.

But how do I do that ?

I tried MiniTool but the free version does not support Dynamic Disk resizing.
I looked at EaseUS but I'm not sure if it actually shrinks the container size.

**Update**
As I'm trying again, I left about 300GB *unallocated* and started the installation procedure.

I was able to create a swap space with 953MiB. But after that I tried to create a /boot partition and it says

> "Failed to add new device."
>   local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Should it not do that since the entire disk is under Windows' control ?